# How to configure tomcat java application in apache web server?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, web

I just configured the tomcat java application in apache like below.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/app_name
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/app_name
</VirtualHost>
```

Later I enabled site using `a2ensite adavipalem.conf` and restarted the server.

When I try to access from the browser by hitting like >> `domain.com`
I got something like below at browser.

```
    Internal Server Error

    The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

    Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at adavipalem.com Port 80
```

Can anyone help me where should I have to change this config?

Regards,

Comment: Any errors in httpd's `error.log` or Tomcat's `catalina.out`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solved the issue on my own. There is no problem with config what I have mentioned earlier..

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/app_name
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/app_name
</VirtualHost>
```

I just forgot to enable the

```
a2enmod proxy_http
```

Due to this, I can't able to make the HTTP request ultimately I was stuck at apache itself. Later I enabled proxy_http, Now it is proxying me to tomcat url I can able to refer the tomcat app now.

Thanks